# Partial derivatives of $xy^2/(x^2+y^2)$ at the origin

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, derivatives, partial-derivative

I noticed that this is a big black hole in my understanding of partial derivatives at the point. I don't know how to count it:

$$
f(x,y) = \frac {xy^2}{x^2+y^2}
$$

$$
\frac {df}{dx}(0,0)=\lim_{t\to 0} \frac{f(t,0)-f(0,0)}{t} =\lim_{t\to 0} \frac {\frac{t*0}{t^2}}{t} = \frac {0}{0}=???
$$
I don't know how to finish it.

Comment: Note that the expression for $f$ is not defined at $(0,0)$. I guess you mean $f(0,0)=0$, in which case we have $f(x,0)=0$ for all $x$, hence $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(0,0)=0$.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I thought it isn't necessary in this case. 
Thank you!!!

Answer (score 1):

Your solution was correct up to this  step:
$$ \lim_{t\to 0} \frac {\frac{t*0}{t^2}}{t} = \frac{0}{0}$$
The theorem about limit of quotient being the quotient of limits does not apply when the denominator has limit zero. Therefore, you should continue to transform and simplify the quotient:
$$ \lim_{t\to 0} \frac {\frac{t*0}{t^2}}{t} = \lim_{t\to 0} \frac {0/t^2}{t} = \lim_{t\to 0} \frac {0}{t} = \lim_{t\to 0} 0 = 0$$